# Как преобразовать данный метод с помощью Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Входной тип данных: `Map<String, List<Model>>`

Выходной тип данных: `Map<String, List<Entity>>`

Для преобразования Model в Entity создал конструктор в классе Entity

```
 public Entity(@NonNull Model model) {
    ...
}
```

Изначально написал таким образом, но результат одна пара key-value в Map

Я так понимаю, нужно делать Collectors.toMap(...) или reduce(..), а не findFirst(), но каким образом?

```
        final var entities = pr.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> Map.of(e.getKey(), e.getValue()
                    .stream()
                    .map(Entity::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException());
```

На данный момент переписал таким образом, но выглядит конечно не особо "красиво"

```
    final var map = new HashMap<String, List<Program>>();
pr.forEach((k, v) -> {
    final var models = v.stream().map(Program::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    map.put(k, models );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно просто использовать `Collectors.toMap` и для лаконичности применив `keySet()` для исходной мапы моделей:

```java
Map<String, List<Model>> models = getModelMap(); // исходная мапа
Map<String, List<Entity>> entities = models
    .keySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        k -> k,
        k -> models.get(k)
                .stream()
                .map(Entity::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

---

Для `entrySet` можно применить `Collectors.groupingBy` и "новый" коллектор `Collectors.flatMapping`, добавленный в Java 9:

```java
Map<String, List<Model>> models = getModelMap(); // исходная мапа
Map<String, List<Entity>> entities = models
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.flatMapping(
            e -> e.getValue().stream().map(Entity::new), // Stream<Entity>
            Collectors.toList()
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
Map<String, List<Model> map = getMap();
map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> Map.entry(
            entry.getKey(), 
            entry.getValue().stream()
                .map(Entity::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

берем стрим по `entrySet`, каждую `Map.Entry` превращаем в новую, нужную `Map.Entry` (ключ тот же самый, значение - новый лист), собираем все обратно в `map`

Можно сделать удобнее с помощью библиотеки [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```java
Map<String, Entity> collect = EntryStream.of(map)
    .flatMapValues(models -> models.stream().map(Entity::new))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: 1) создавать лишние экземпляры при помощи Map.entry необязательно :) 2) В Java 9 был добавлен коллектор `Collectors.flatMapping`, так что `StreamEx` потребуется только если автор использует версию не выше Java 8.